# mysql select only next week data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date field in my database i.e film_release_date.

So what is mysql query to fetch the next week data from table.

I run this query but its not working properlly.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%e-%b-%Y') AS release_date 
FROM gf_film 
WHERE 
    MONTH(film_release_date)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND YEAR(film_release_date)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND film_release_date>=(CURRENT_DATE) 
ORDER BY film_release_date DESC
```

Actually its for movie website i have several movies in my database so i need a query which fetch every next week movie that means movies that will release in next week means next friday.If i run this today i.e 13 then it shows all movies between 15 to 22 and if run this between 15 to 22 then it shows data from 22 to 29

Comment: define 'not working properly'

Comment: yes the query not fetch next week data actually the week starts from every friday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set @d := date_add(CURRENT_DATE, interval 7 day);
set @week_start := @d - interval (dayofweek(@d) + 1) day;
set @week_end := @d + interval (6 - dayofweek(@d)) day;
SELECT *,
       DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%e-%b-%Y') AS release_date
FROM gf_film
WHERE film_release_date between @week_start and @week_end
ORDER BY film_release_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

to get next week data you can simple apply below logic :

```
SELECT something FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAYS)
```

[REFERENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: listen week starts in every friday. I have clearly mention that film related data so if i run this query on monady then it should return data which will be released after next friday

Comment: @pravat, there is only 1 Friday in each week btw

Comment: yes i knew that i just need to know if i run this query in between friday to friday then it should return data from friday to next friday do u get me??

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but none of the answers works properly. You can use yearweek function to get week number of the year. So you get the week number of now (this week) or now() + interval 7 day to get next week. Examples:

THIS WEEK

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%e-%b-%Y') AS release_date 
  FROM gf_film 

WHERE YEARWEEK(film_release_date) = YEARWEEK(NOW())

ORDER BY film_release_date DESC
```

NEXT WEEK

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%e-%b-%Y') AS release_date 
  FROM gf_film 

WHERE YEARWEEK(film_release_date) = YEARWEEK(NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)

ORDER BY film_release_date DESC
```