# Want to fetch next week data from mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to fetch next week data. My date is 2/10/2015 and today is friday. I want to fetch next week data that starts from Monday. I refered [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671489/mysql-select-only-next-week-data).
I am using codeigniter so what is the process to write the sql query in codeigniter?

Comment: Find something usefull on [this link](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/99-Finding-Next-Monday-using-MySQL-Dates.html).

Comment: Thanks Tpokja...Will sure try for this.

Comment: Sometimes [google helps](https://www.google.ba/search?q=mysql+select+next+monday&oq=mysql+select+next+monday&aqs=chrome..69i57.7182j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of you'll need to get the date of the next monday with

```
$next_monday = new DateTime('next monday');
```

Then get the end of the week (if you need it):

```
$date = $next_monday->format('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59'; //Get monday at 23:59
$end_week  = strtotime("+7 day", $date); //Get  sunday at 23:59
```

And then in your Codeigniter model, making use of [Active Records](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html):

```
public function nextWeekData($monday, $sunday){
    $this->db->where("your_date_field >= '". $monday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' AND your_date_field <= '". $sunday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'");
    $this->db->get('your_table');
    return $this->db->result_array(); // If you want an array
    // return $this->db->result(); // If you want StdClass
}
```

So the call from your controller should be:

```
$this->my_model->nextWeekData($next_monday, $end_week);
```

Just remove `$end_week` and the second clausule at the WHERE statement in the model if you dont need upper limit.

This should do it, i think. Code not tested. *Important*: Mind the quotes in the where.